# R built in list of currency symbols?

Tags: r

Does R have any built in list of currency symbols (e.g. `¤ £ € $ ¢ ¥ ₧ ƒ`) ?

Along the lines of

```
letters
 # [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

but for currencies?

Comment: Currency/exchange specific packages might have it.

Answer (score 3):

Base R does not have any built in list of currency symbols.

The easiest solution to build one is *imho* scraping wikipedia [list of currencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies) for data using `rvest` package.

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies"

currency_tab_wiki <- url %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div/table[1]") %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

currency <- as_tibble(currency_tab_wiki[[1]])

head(currency, 4)
```

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  `State or territory[1]` `Currency[1][2]`   `Symbol[D] orAbbrev.[3]` `ISO code[2]` Fractionalunit `Numberto basic`
  <chr>                   <chr>              <chr>                    <chr>         <chr>          <chr>           
1 Abkhazia                Abkhazian apsar[E] (none)                   (none)        (none)         (none)          
2 Abkhazia                Russian ruble      ₽                        RUB           Kopek          100             
3 Afghanistan             Afghan afghani     ؋                        AFN           Pul            100             
4 Akrotiri and Dhekelia   Euro               €                        EUR           Cent           100
```